# how to Disable prompt Ghostscript box when exec command from php?

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to convert PDF file to JPG using Ghostscript and PHP and below is the code that works for me.
`exec('"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin64.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sDEVICE=png16m -r200 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=test%d.jpg test.pdf');`
But the issue is when exec command one Ghostscript windows prompt and I want to disable the showing command box.

Below is a screenshot of Ghostscript windows showing when converting file.
[image]

Comment: please explain how can i change from windows command to console exe??

Comment: Use gswin64c.exe instead of gswin64.exe